# Armenian fonts dosn't work in fontface css3

Tags: html, css, font-face

a font-face in my web site doesn't work... it's a Armenian font and it doesn't work... i need your help

this is my example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/w4zQv/

and you can download a font from url

the font should look like this

[image]

thanks for help

Comment: There's no relation with JQuery. Removing tag.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? If so, please accept an answer or add your own solution below.

Comment: no. that font's doesn't work on the web :

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

What browser are you using? I use Chrome and it works perfectly. Make sure your browser supports .ttf, not all browsers do.

Comment: i use a Firefox.. and other fonts work perfectly. but this Armenian fonts doesn't work

Comment: In my Chrome it works perfectly. What versions of FF and Chrome are you using?

Comment: last version look an image, the font should look like that